# Reset file selection blueimp fileupload - angularJS

Tags: angularjs, blueimp

I am looking for a way to reset the file selection, in case the user choose an invalid file for instance.

From [this issue](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1223) on gitHub, it appears that you need to unbind the event in order to reset the file selection, now, how do I do such a thing in AngularJS?

Markup:

```
<form name="applyForm" data-file-upload="model.uploadOptionsResume" action="{{model.application_url}}" method="{{model.method}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
     <input type="file" data-ng-model='model.formData.resume' name="resume" data-ng-disabled="" data-valid-file data-my-validate data-value-required="true">
     <submit data-ng-disabled="applyForm.$invalid || innerLoader" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:99%;"  data-ng-click="submit(); model.submitFormApplicant()">
                            Apply
                            <!-- submitFormApplicant() check if a file is selected and if not does regular submit -->
                        </submit>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that unbinding the event is required because of the closed over variables that are captured with the `.on('click', ...` anonymous function. I am pretty sure your code can be structured to not rely on the closure, thus removing the need to unbind from ng-click. However, without seeing your code, I cannot be sure that closures are your problem nor can I really recommend how restructure your code if they are.

Comment: A standard form, with a button that bind to the submit() function with ng-click.

Edired: added a summarized example of my code.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Where is the code where you are actually using the plugin?

Comment: Well, that's all of it, the submit() event is predefined by the blueimp library js files

Comment: @OlegTikhonov If you know the event name that you need to unbind, I suppose `angular.element().unbind()` would work. Sorry I can't be anymore help.